# Product of compact set and a vector

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I'm studying Mathematical Analysis on my own. Maybe this will be a trivial question but I haven't found the way to prove the following, and I don't have a teacher to guide me,

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set, and let $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ be a vector. Prove that $A\times \{x\}$ is compact

I'll appreciate any advice.

PD: don't use the fact that product of compact sets is compact. In fact, the result prove that assertion

Comment: What definition of compactness do you assume?

Comment: @enedil A set is compact if every open cover of the set has a finite subcover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know how product topology is defined. Since your question deals with $\mathbb{R}^n$, I refrain from giving you the most general definitionbut I will try to answer your question in a way that gives you insight and motivation for the general case. So, let's assume that $\mathbb{R}^n$ has been equipped with the Euclidean distance
$$d(\vec{x},\vec{y}) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2}$$

**Irrelevant fact:** It turns out that for finite dimensional spaces, all norms are equivalent, but we don't need this now.

Anyway, the distance defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ makes it possible to say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n,b_n) = (\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n,\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n)$.

So, if you want to use compactness in the sense of sequential compactness, if $A$ is compact, then for any sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $A$, there exists a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that $a_{n_k}$ converges in $A$ to some point like $a \in A$. You can now easily see that any sequence in $A\times \{x\}$ must have a subsequence that converges to something in $A\times \{x\}$. Can you see why this is true?

If you want to use open covers instead, then you should first convince yourself that any open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ contains an open rectangle of the form $(a_1,a_2)\times (b_1,b_2)$ around each of its points. Then a cover for $A \times \{x\}$ will give you a cover for $A$. What can you conclude from this knowing that $A$ is compact?

**Another almost irrelevant but important fact**

> Sequential compactness and compactness by open covers are equivalent in metric spaces

Comment: Oh! Excuse me, I wasn't so specific. I was trying to prove it just using open covers, but this already give me the clue. Thanks!

Comment: @Edonbrayn You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In the usual topology, a compact subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equivalent to being closed and bounded. Try to convince yourself that $A\times\{x\}$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.